# Постоянная подгрузка данных из БД

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

на форме есть структура(table) и форма с полями для ввода. Когда пользователь вводит информацию в поля и жмет на кнопку, то данные добавляются в БД и оттуда подгружаются в структуру. Нужно разделить запрос так, чтобы данные, после нажатия, добавлялись в БД, а структура(table) автоматически подгружала данные в себя через какие-то промежутки времени из БД, без каких-либо нажатий и действий. 
Вот код формы со скриптом:

```
    <form id="myform" action="for_db.php" method="post" >
                                    <div class="trading__buy-row">
                                        <div class="trading__buy-row-title">Price</div>
                                        <input type="text" id="price" name="price" class="priceField" onchange=f()>
                                        <div class="trading__buy-row-title2">111</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="trading__buy-row">
                                        <div class="trading__buy-row-title">Amount</div>
                                        <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" class="amountField" onchange=f()>
                                        <div class="trading__buy-row-title2">111</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="trading__buy-row">
                                        <div class="trading__buy-row-title">Total</div>
                                        <input type="text" id="total" name="total" class="totalField" >
                                        <div class="trading__buy-row-title2">111</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="trading__buy-text">Trade commission: <span>0.1%</span></div>
                                    <!--<div class="btn btn--buy" id="sub" >BUY</div> -->
                                    <input type="submit" value="Buy" class="button">
                                    <span id="result"></span>
                                </form>

                                <table class="rows"> 
                                </table>


                                <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".button").bind("click", function() {

        var price = jQuery('.priceField').val();
        var amount = jQuery('.amountField').val();
        var total = jQuery('.totalField').val();

        jQuery('.priceField').val('');
        jQuery('.amountField').val('');
        jQuery('.totalField').val('');

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "for_db.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {price:price, amount:amount, total: total}, // Передаем данные для записи
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                if (result){ 
                    jQuery('.rows tr').remove();
                    jQuery('.rows').append(function(){
                        var res = '';
                        for(var i = 0; i < result.ordersbuy.total.length; i++){
                            res += '<tr><td>' + result.ordersbuy.id[i] + '</td><td>' + result.ordersbuy.price[i] + '</td><td>' + result.ordersbuy.amount[i] + '</td><td>' + result.ordersbuy.total[i] + '</td></tr>';
                        }
                            return res;
                    });
                    console.log(result);
                }else{
                    alert(result.message);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Файл for_db.php:

```
<?php
 session_start();
    include_once('db.php');
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
         $sesion_id=$_SESSION['userid'];
    }

$price = $_POST['price'];
$amount =$_POST['amount'];
$total = $_POST['total'];


/** Если нам передали ID то обновляем */
if($price && $amount && $total){
    //вставляем запись в БД
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `ordersbuy` (`id`,`price`,`amount`,`total`) VALUES ('$sesion_id','$price','$amount','$total')");
$query2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `ordersbuy` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    while($row = $query2->fetch_assoc()){
        $ordersbuy['id'][] = $row['id'];
        $ordersbuy['price'][] = $row['price'];
        $ordersbuy['amount'][] = $row['amount'];
        $ordersbuy['total'][] = $row['total'];
    }
    $message = 'Все хорошо';
}else{
    $message = 'Не удалось записать и извлечь данные';
}

/** Возвращаем ответ скрипту */

// Формируем масив данных для отправки
$out = array(
    'message' => $message,
    'ordersbuy' => $ordersbuy
);

// Устанавливаем заголовот ответа в формате json
header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');

// Кодируем данные в формат json и отправляем
echo json_encode($out);
?>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ Аякс запрос на подгрузку данных }, 3000);` и через каждые 3 секунды будут подгружаться данные. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk не могли бы вы показать как надо правильно написать запрос?

Answer (score 0):

Я когда то использовал такую функцию, в нём я использовал

```
setInterval(() => {
  Функция, которая отправляет ajax запрос, и в нём обработчик ответа
}, промежуток отправления запроса)
```

У меня был чат, который показывал новые сообщения без обновления страницы

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения вместо `setTimeout(function(){ Аякс запрос на подгрузку данных }, 3000);` нужно использовать `setInterval(function(){ Аякс запрос на подгрузку данных }, 3000);`
`setTimeout` - устанавливает задержку выполнения скрипта
`setInterval` - в цикле запускает выполнение скрипта через определенное время

Вместо `jQuery` удобней использовать `$`.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").bind("click", function() {

        var price = $('.priceField').val();
        var amount = $('.amountField').val();
        var total = $('.totalField').val();

        $('.priceField').val('');
        $('.amountField').val('');
        $('.totalField').val('');

        $.ajax({
            url: "for_db.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {price:price, amount:amount, total: total}, // Передаем данные для записи
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                if (result){ 
                    $('.rows tr').remove();
                    $('.rows').append(function(){
                        var res = '';
                        for(var i = 0; i < result.ordersbuy.total.length; i++){
                            res += '<tr><td>' + result.ordersbuy.id[i] + '</td><td>' + result.ordersbuy.price[i] + '</td><td>' + result.ordersbuy.amount[i] + '</td><td>' + result.ordersbuy.total[i] + '</td></tr>';
                        }
                            return res;
                    });
                    console.log(result);
                }else{
                    alert(result.message);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
    
    
//Через каждые 3 секунды посылаем аякс запрос    
 setInterval(function(){ 
 $.ajax({
            url: "for_db.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {refresh:true}, // Передаем данные для записи
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                if (result){ 
                    $('.rows tr').remove();
                    $('.rows').append(function(){
                        var res = '';
                        for(var i = 0; i < result.ordersbuy.total.length; i++){
                            res += '<tr><td>' + result.ordersbuy.id[i] + '</td><td>' + result.ordersbuy.price[i] + '</td><td>' + result.ordersbuy.amount[i] + '</td><td>' + result.ordersbuy.total[i] + '</td></tr>';
                        }
                            return res;
                    });
                    console.log(result);
                }else{
                    alert(result.message);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
 }, 3000);   
    
});
</script>
```

Изменяем файл for_db.php:

```html
<?php
 session_start();
    include_once('db.php');
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
         $sesion_id=$_SESSION['userid'];
    }
    
    //Если существует refresh то просто получаем данные с базы и возвращаем их
    if($_POST['refresh']=="true"){
    $query2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `ordersbuy` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    while($row = $query2->fetch_assoc()){
        $ordersbuy['id'][] = $row['id'];
        $ordersbuy['price'][] = $row['price'];
        $ordersbuy['amount'][] = $row['amount'];
        $ordersbuy['total'][] = $row['total'];
    }
    $out = array(
    'ordersbuy' => $ordersbuy
);
    // Устанавливаем заголовот ответа в формате json
header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');

// Кодируем данные в формат json и отправляем
echo json_encode($out);

//Прекращаем выполнения скрипта
exit;
    }
    

$price = $_POST['price'];
$amount =$_POST['amount'];
$total = $_POST['total'];


/** Если нам передали ID то обновляем */
if($price && $amount && $total){
    //вставляем запись в БД
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `ordersbuy` (`id`,`price`,`amount`,`total`) VALUES ('$sesion_id','$price','$amount','$total')");
$query2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `ordersbuy` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    while($row = $query2->fetch_assoc()){
        $ordersbuy['id'][] = $row['id'];
        $ordersbuy['price'][] = $row['price'];
        $ordersbuy['amount'][] = $row['amount'];
        $ordersbuy['total'][] = $row['total'];
    }
    $message = 'Все хорошо';
}else{
    $message = 'Не удалось записать и извлечь данные';
}

/** Возвращаем ответ скрипту */

// Формируем масив данных для отправки
$out = array(
    'message' => $message,
    'ordersbuy' => $ordersbuy
);

// Устанавливаем заголовот ответа в формате json
header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');

// Кодируем данные в формат json и отправляем
echo json_encode($out);
?>
```